# computer doesn't recognize hdd plugged in via esata

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, esata

I recently got a new eSATA HDD enclosure and when I plug my HDD into my eSATA enclosure and then plug the eSATA enclosure into my computer and turn the enclosure on my computer doesn't recognize it. It doesn't come up in Computer Management -> Disk Management.

I assume it should be? Is perchance my eSATA enclosure bad? Maybe the eSATA adapter on my computer is bad? I don't have another eSATA device with which to do any testing. The HDD is good because I was accessing it directly via regular SATA yesterday. I tried 2x SATA HDDs in the eSATA enclosure to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the motherboard?  What is the controller used for the E-Sata?

Comment: how the power is supplied to the enclosure? is the drive inside the enclosure 2.5" or 3.5"?

Comment: I've tried it on two OEM systems. A ThinkPad W510 and a Compaq Presario SR1900NX. The ThinkPad has an eSATA port and for the Compaq I'm using a SATA -> eSATA adapter. As for the power supply...  it's plugged in and the light on the enclosure is on. The HDD inside is a 3.5". Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You must enter your BIOS utility and make sure the SATA port your eSATA corresponds to is operating in AHCI mode and has Hot Plug enabled. If you are not sure which, just enable to all SATA ports.

If your SATA ports are operating in IDE mode you will have to modify a configuration on your Windows before changing to AHCI, or your system will fail to initialize.

Open `regedit.exe` and go to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlset\Services\msahci\
```

Change the value of `Start` to `0` before rebooting and changing your BIOS to AHCI mode.